# social icons in a row when on mobile view

Tags: css, icons, row

i want my social icons to be in a row direction (on the left side) when in mobile view. When in desktop view, icons should be on the far right side in a column, and i did that using float:right, but what should I change to get them in a horizontal line (inline) on the left side?
This is my html:

```
 <div class="socialico">
            <div id="social-test">
                    <ul class="social">
                      <li><a class = "facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/bay42.io/"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                      <li><a class = "instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/bay42.io/"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></a></i></li>
                      <li><a class = "linkedin" href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/bay42-banja-luka/"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div> <!--social-test div-->
    </div>
```

and here is my css:

```
.socialico{
             position: relative;
             float: right;
             margin-top: -8%;
             color: #fff;
             animation: slideInRight 1.5s;
            } 
         #social-test ul li{
             padding-bottom: 10px;
        }
        .socialico ul li a:hover{  
    color: #C8A962;
    animation: bounceIn 6s;
        }
        .socialico ul li a { 
    color:#fff;
}
```

also, here is my css for mobile view:

```
.socialico{

            position: relative;
            float:left;
            margin-top: -8%;
            color: #fff;
            animation: slideInRight 1.5s;
           } 
        #social-test ul li{
            display: inline-block;
       }
       .socialico ul li a:hover{  
   color: #C8A962;
   animation: bounceIn 6s;
       }
       .socialico ul li a { 
   color:#fff;
   display: inline-block;
```

}
        }

Comment: Let me just give you a suggestion and rid of floats and work with flex: https://css-tricks.com/dont-overthink-flexbox-grids/ ...it will do wonders for your responsive

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set the `ul` display to `flex` and set the `flex-direction` to `row`.

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 576px) {
  .socialico {
    float: left;
  }
  #social-test ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
  }
}
```